# How do I cancel an event handler in JavaScript or jQuery from another event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the submit button is clicked that event is also handled by some code that submits the form - I would share that code too but I'm having trouble finding it. My problem is that I want to be able to cancel the form submission from the button click event (as you can see I tried several methods of doing so), but instead what happens is that the validation message appears that the hours don't match up and then a few seconds later a message appears saying that the form was submitted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // find total hours
  var reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#TotalHours").text());
  if (!reportedTotalHours) {
    reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#EventDuration").text());
    $("#TotalHours").text(reportedTotalHours)
  }

  // handle button click
  $('input[type=button]').on('click', function(evt) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Close')
      return true;
    var totalHours = 0;
    $('select.dropdownQuestion').each(function(i, sel) {
      var hours = $(sel).find(":selected").text();
      var f = parseFloat(hours);
      if (f != 0 && !Number.isNaN(f))
        totalHours += f;
    });

    // validate that hours are within a quarter hour of each other
    var difference = Math.abs(totalHours - reportedTotalHours);
    if (difference >= 0.25) // discrepancy must be less than a quarter hour
    {
      alert("Total of hours for each activity must equal " + reportedTotalHours + ".");
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $("#SkipSave").val('true');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

I think the problem might be that I'm in a button click event handler and I'm trying to cancel a form submit event instead, but if I change this:

```js
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(evt) {
```

to

```js
$('form').submit(function(evt) {
```

then the validation never seems to happen at all.

Comment: You cannot cancel event handlers. Once fired they will run to completion.

Comment: input[type=button] does not submit the form! (only input[type=submit]). You must have some other code that submits the form. Please show that.

Comment: Try capturing the event on a higher level element, and using prevent default to do not propagate